# allocPhysPages function in System

Tags: gem5

I am trying to implement a custom physical allocation for which I need to modify the allocPhysPages() function in the System class. There is this section of code in that function

```
 AddrRange m5opRange(0xffff0000, 0x100000000);
    if (m5opRange.contains(next_return_addr)) {
        warn("Reached m5ops MMIO region\n");
        return_addr = 0xffffffff;
        pagePtr_arr[chiplet_id] = 0xffffffff >> PageShift;
    }
```

My question is can I comment out this section of code which checks if the allocated physical address is in the MMIO region or not. I don't want to take care of the MMIO region to reduce the complexity. If I comment this out then would it lead to any kind of failure during simulation?

Note: allocPhysPages() is located in src/sim/system.cc

Comment: I am just going to update, that I tested with a couple of SPEC benchmarks and that didn't lead to any error. My guess is that this code tries to emulate the MMIO region of memory and how it is taken into account for memory allocation.